# Accessing Ember environment config (ENV) from addon?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an addon which uses a different host for a service in development and at runtime. I believed the solution to this would be to define the hostname in the config/environment.js of the application and to have a the service pick it up as follows:

```js
import ENV from '../config/environment';

export default AjaxService.extend({
     host: ENV.APP.serviceHost,
     ...
```

This however doesn't work as it believes that the path to the environment.js file is within the scope of the addon instead of the main application.
What is the right way to do this when the name of the application in which this addon is included is not known?

I am using Ember 2.11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm aware of 2 approaches for this:

### Option 1

[ember-config-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-config-service)

This addon allows to access config via injected service. It solved the same issue for me.

### Option 2

Manually pass config value via re-export.

```js
// my-addon/app/services/my-ajax.js

// import config being in the app namespace
import ENV from '../config/environment';

import Service from 'my-addon/services/my-ajax';

export default Service.extend({
  apiURL: ENV.APP.apiURL
});
```

```js
/// my-addon/addon/services/my-ajax.js

export default AjaxService.extend({
  init() {
    console.log('api url in addon', this.apiUrl);
  }
})
```

Comment: That seems to provide what I needed, thanks. I'll update this after the weekend.

Answer (score 4):

With recent versions of Ember, you can get the environment config from the container.

```
Ember.getOwner(this).resolveRegistration('config:environment')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this package in my projects to good effect:

https://github.com/null-null-null/ember-get-config